# Adding fields to a submit form

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

Hi I'm having trouble adding fields to a form and retrieving them in the controller.

I can easily add fields to a form on button click which is what using:

```
$('#addButton').click(function()
{
     $('#EBASTab').append($('<tr><td>Hello</td><td><input style="height:' + 10 + 'px; width:' + 100 + 'px;"></input></td></tr>'));
```

but when I try retrieve the forms data using:

```
$value = $this->request->data;
```

The field I added to the bottom of the table doesn't get taken in.

Any idea how I can add the fields to my cakephp form?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you expect the data to go? I'm not familiar with cake, but I thought putting a __name__ in there would help.

Comment: Yep that was the answer thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no name attribute, that's why not in post data. Add a `name="data[Model][field]"` attribute to the input.

Answer (score 1):

you need name attribute in the input, and catch data using that name.

Answer (score 1):

Have to add like this

```
$('#EBASTab').append($('<tr><td>Hello</td><td><input type="file" class="uploadFile" name="data[Album][image]">'));
```

Comment: You dont have to add it like this all you need to do is name="Whatever". You don't need brackets.

Comment: brackets are represented for model and fields. Its format for cakephp

Comment: Alright cool well was just saying works without it aswel but ill give ye a + vote for a correct answer :)